# Как установить цвет кнопки во ViewHolder, взятый из JSON?

Tags: android

Кнопка btnColor находится в item.xml. Как изменить ее background на цвет, взятый из json? 
JSON:

```
{  
      "id":11,
      "category":1,
      "parameters":[  
         {  
            "k":"COLOR",
            "v":"#9fdce1"
         }
      ],
      "rating":5
   }
```

Класс Info:

```
public class Info {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private int category;
    @SerializedName("parameters")
    @Expose
    private List<Product.Parameter> parameters = null;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private float rating;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(int category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Product.Parameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(List<Product.Parameter> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public class Parameter {

        @SerializedName("k")
        @Expose
        private String k;
        @SerializedName("v")
        @Expose
        private String v;

        public String getK() {
            return k;
        }

        public void setK(String k) {
            this.k = k;
        }

        public String getV() {
            return v;
        }

        public void setV(String v) {
            this.v = v;
        }

    }
```

Код адаптера:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (this.getItemViewType(position)) {
            case INFO:
                InfoViewHolder infoViewHolder = (InfoViewHolder) holder;
                Info info = (Info) items.get(position);
                infoViewHolder.ratingBar.setRating(info.getRating());
                infoViewHolder.btnColor.setBackground(); // ?
                break;
        }
    }
```

И нужно ли и как преобразовать формат цвета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод

`public static int parseColor (String colorString)`

примерно так:

```
infoViewHolder.btnColor.setBackground(Color.parseColor(info.getParameters().get(position).getV()));
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас цвет приходит в виде строки. Нужно:

- удалить первый символ "#"
- добавить впереди "FF", чтобы не получился прозрачный цвет
- преобразовать HEX-строку в `Integer`
- установить цвет кнопке `infoViewHolder.btnColor.setBackgroundColor(int)`

Comment: Eugene Krivenjа, а как взять строку с цветом?

Comment: `info.getParameters().get(0).getV();`

Comment: Только будьте внимательны, возможно вам нужно будет искать цвет в списке параметров по признаку где `getK() == "COLOR"` !!! А не брать единственный параметр, как в частном случае, приведенном в вопросе.

Comment: Eugene Krivenja, не работает, сделала так: String color = info.getParameters().get(0).getV();
                if(color.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                } else {
                    color.substring(1);
                    String newColor = "FF" + color;
                    int hex = (int) Long.parseLong(newColor, 16);
                    infoViewHolder.btnColor.setBackgroundColor(hex);
                }

Comment: А что именно не работает-то? Подозреваю, что `substring` вы неверно используете. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)